# How to properly style excel file with laravel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to export data from database into excel file.this is the code i'm using to display my data into the newly created excel file:

```
$name = 'fiche signaletique '.date('d-m-Y H-i');  

        Excel::create($name, function($excel) use($cards, $count) {

            $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($cards, $count) {

                $i = 2;
                $rows = $count;
                $rows++;

                $sheet->setHeight(1, 25);
                $sheet->setAutoSize(true);
                $sheet->setBorder('A1:AI'.$rows, 'thin');

                $sheet->row(1, array(

                    'Client (Société)',
                    'Numéro Fiche',
                    'Forme juridique',
                    'Capital Social',
                    'Type'

                ))->cells('A1:AI1', function($cells) {

                    $cells->setBackground('#1E86CF');
                    $cells->setFont(array(
                        'family'     => 'Calibri',
                        'size'       => '12',
                        'bold'       =>  true
                    ));
                    $cells->setFontColor('#ffffff');

                });

                foreach ($cards as $key => $card) {
                    $sheet->row($i, array(

                        $card->clientsociete['company'], 
                        $card->card_code, 
                        $card->legal_form,
                        $card->share_capital,
                        $card->group

                    ))->cells('A'.$i, function($cells) {

                        $cells->setBackground('#D9D9D9');

                    });

                    $i++;
                }    

            });

        })->download('xls');
```

The problem that i have is that the last column doesn't have any style(no font or background color).

Comment: Can the cause be that you only stale one row? 'A1:AI1'
Should't it be A+Row:AI+Row ?

Comment: i should change "->cells('A1:AI1', function($cells)" to what ?